# Кот, мною купленный-таки, (-) суперкот

Tags: тире

Можете сказать, нужно ли ставить тире в случае, если подлежащие и сказуемое, которые через тире должны были бы писаться, посредством причастного или деепричастного оборота или сложноподчинённого предложения разъеденены?

Например: *1) Кот, мною купленный-таки, (-) суперкот; 2) Собака, которая у мамы живёт, (-) очень умная собака; 3) Цыплёнок,  ко мне пришедший,  (-) хороший цыплёнок.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю да, запятая и тире - нужны, потому что там пропущено *"это"*. Кот, купленный мною-таки, - *это* "суперкот"(является супер котом).

Кот - это подлежащее из обрубленного предложения и"суперкот" сказуемое, но относятся они к разным основам(?).

Вылизывается кот, купленный вчера в магазине, - таки это суперкот.

*Вылизывает кот, купленный вчера в магазине,* - первая фраза.

*Таки это "суперкот",* - вторая, или опуская "это", *таки "суперкот"*.

Либо это вообще три однородных обращения:

*Цыпленок*, *пришедший*, *милый*, - все отвечают на вопрос *кто?*. Тогда запятые...